# wav file limited to 35 minutes in length?

Tags: audio, format, wav

I recorded 13 hours of audio to a wav file (48kHz sampling rate) with the Android App "AudioRec". The file is ~4,2G in size. 
I then transfered the file to my gentoo linux and tried to open it with ffmpeg, vlc, mpv and audacity, sox. In all applications the file has a length of exactly 35 minutes.

If I open the file in audacity with Import->Rawdata it indeed reads the whole file as 13 hours sound file. But if I export the file again with same format settings (48kHz,mono,pcm_s16le) to wav still no application is able to read it with 13 hours lenght... So I guess I have to split the file in 34:59 minutes chunks to use them (my intention was to feed the 13 hours to sox to create a spectrogram)...

Is there anyone who has an explanation why there is this 35 minutes restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I maybe found the answer myself:

> Well, there is no way to do this right. RIFF/WAVE only uses 32 bits to
>   store lengths, so anything >4 GiB won't fit. This is comparable to a
>   paper form that asks for your age, but only offerss two places for the
>   digits; if you're 102 years old, you might write "02" or "99", but you
>   can't specify your true age.
>   https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/bugs/213/#2fc6
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Limitations